# .NET webservice client null properties in result

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

Upon seemingly successfully consuming a web service in a c# console application, inspection of the returned object shows the properties are all null!

After much searching for answers, I've tracked the issue down to a namespace problem in the SOAP XML -- using fiddler, my slightly modified SOAP response looks like so:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <MyResponse xmlns="http://foo.com">
        <FIRST_NM xmlns="">Michael</FIRST_NM>
      </MyResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The only part I added was the:

...FIRST_NM **xmlns=""**>Michael... (the bold part) using fiddler.

Once I did this as a man-in-the-middle during a debug session -- voila!  The FIRST_NM value of "Michael" was displayed to me in my client app for the first time ever.  I decided to try this because I noticed that the request going out from my client had such an attribute, and the response did not.

OK, so diagnosis completed.  I am turning to the step where I make it work.  Assuming I have no control over the server side of things, I tried opening up the Reference.cs file and making some changes, such as changing this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
 public string FIRST_NM {
   get {
     return this.fIRST_NMField;
   }
   set {
     this.fIRST_NMField = value;
     this.RaisePropertyChanged("FIRST_NM");
   }
 }
```

to this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Namespace="http://foo.com", Order=3)]
public string FIRST_NM {
...
```

I added **Namespace="http://foo.com",** to the XmlElementAttribute.  My thinking was that without the xmlns="" that the namespace "http://foo.com" was inherited from parent "MyResponse" tag and I'd get a match.

That, however, did not work.  Any direction you all could point me in would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the following line(s) completely from the .NET-generated code:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
```

I suppose since the namespace was inherited from the parent tag that it was actually "Qualified" not "Unqualified".  Removing that led to the default Form behavior, None (which defers to the document).

Thank you to the community -- I figured this out largely based on recommendations I found in related SO Questions.